# What is the term for sentences like these?

Tags: single-word-requests

What are sentences like "*men are to women as culture is to nature*" called?

Answer (score 7):

This is called an analogy, and it can be categorized as a complex sentence: "men are to women" is an independent clause, and "as culture is to nature" is a dependent clause.